# Rails: Displaying Users on Index Page

Tags: css, ruby-on-rails, indexing, grid

I'm trying to style the Users Index page in my project via CSS so that the User Photos and Text appear in a 'Grid' fashion as users register and are added to the database. My users/index.html.erb below:

```
<%= link_to user do %>
   <%= image_tag user.photo.url(:small) %>
<% end %><br />

<%= user.first_name %>
<%= user.last_name %><br />
<%= user.city %><br />
<%= user.country %><br /><br />

<% if current_user and current_user.admin %>
  <%= link_to image_tag("edit.png", {:alt => 'Edit User'}), edit_user_path(user), :method => :get %>
  <%= link_to image_tag("delete.png", {:alt => 'Delete User'}), user, method: :delete, data: { confirm: 'Are you sure you want to delete this User?' } %><br /><br />
<% end %>
```

I'd like to set it up so that the User Photo appears above the name, city and country with the next User appearing alongside etc etc. The Edit and Delete will display via an Admin filter. I've added some breaks where needed. I've tried variants of floats, relative positions etc but can't seem to get it working... any ideas?

Many Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [Bootstrap](http://twitter.github.io/bootstrap/scaffolding.html) or any other grid framework for your need.

I have used bootstrap to demonstrate the layout you want. Hope this helps

```
<div class="container">
  <div class="row">
    <div class="span2">
     ...
    </div>
    <div class="span2">
     ...
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

See [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/anpsmn/F6SkZ/1/)

**Update:**

See [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/anpsmn/F6SkZ/5/)

All you need is to give a width to the box and float it so that it shows up in a grid layout.

```
.box {
  width: 140px;
  float: left;
  background: #f5f5f5;
  border: 1px solid #e1e1e1;
  padding: 2px;
  border-radius: 3px;
  margin: 10px 5px 5px 10px;
}
```

Comment: Nice thought Anpsmn but we're not allowed to use Bootstrap (College Project) and have to create all out own styling... sorry I should have added that in my question. I have managed to get some semblance of a 'grid' going using the Product Tables layout from the Agile Development for Rails book but if there is a better way I'm still open to ideas...

Comment: I have updated the answer with a new fiddle. You can also inspect the bootstrap elements and see what styles are added to learn more on how they have produced a grid affect and then write your own.

Comment: That CSS hit the spot anpsmn, I picked out what I needed from the bootstrap elements as you suggested and I'm sorted! thank you!